# remove MUI Accordion gap when expanded

Tags: javascript, material-ui

I'm trying to have the Accordion MUI component NOT move and NOT apply top and bottom margins to summary elements while it is in the expanded mode. I add this code to the summary element but that's not working. what do you offer me? it worth mentioning that it works on the first accordion but not the others!!!!!!!!!!

```
sx={{
   "&.Mui-expanded": {
   minHeight: 0,
   margin: '12px 0',
   },
   "& .MuiAccordionSummary-content.Mui-expanded": {
   margin: 0,
   }
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used MUI customized accordion and I change its setting to it:
I used my icon. it has a white background and no border and additional padding or margin :))))

```
export const Accordion = styled((props: AccordionProps) => (
    <MuiAccordion disableGutters elevation={0} square {...props} />
))(({ theme }) => ({
    position: 'unset',
    border: 'none',
    boxShadow: 'none',
    maxWidth: 720,
    margin: '12 0',
    '&:before': {
        display: 'none',
        border: 'none'
    }
}));

export const AccordionSummary = styled((props: AccordionSummaryProps) => (
    <MuiAccordionSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />} {...props} />
))(({ theme }) => ({
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    padding: 0,
    flexDirection: 'row',
    '& .MuiAccordionSummary-expandIconWrapper.Mui-expanded': {
        transform: 'rotate(180deg)'
    }
}));

export const AccordionDetails = styled(MuiAccordionDetails)(({ theme }) => ({
    padding: 0,
    border: 'none'
}));

export const FAQText = styled(Typography)({
    maxWidth: 628
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Are you setting this prop on `Accordion` or `AccordionSummary`? I've tested your code on StackBlitz by setting it on `Accordion` element and it worked properly.

Comment: It's not working for me :((